# how do i pick three consecutive letters from an input and append to a list

Tags: python

```
askGene=input("Enter Gene:")

ans=askGene.upper()

print(ans)

newStr=''

start=0

end=0

newList=[]

for i in askGene:

    new=ans[start:end]

    newList.append(new)

    start+=3

    end+=3

print(newList)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: the thing am trying to do is Ask for Gene code Like TTATGTTTTAACGATGCGGCC  and print the code after a triplet ATG and ends before TAG,TAA OR TGA

Comment: Please read and follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  We need a clear description of the problem you're trying to solve, the code you wrote, the incorrect output you have, and the output you want.

Comment: You need to provide these specifics. Please provide a sample input. What you expect as a sample output. Clearly explain what it is that you are trying to do and point out where in your code you think the failure is. Also, if the solution provided is not acceptable, please remove the "accepted" solution until you have received an answer that actually solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
askGene = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR"
newList = [askGene[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(askGene), 3)]
```

This gives the output:

```
['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO', 'PQR']
```

Comment: Thanks but the thing i wanted to do is pick a the gene code from ATG and ends before one of those TAG,TAA or TGA  and stores the gene codes between those

Comment: @KalkidanTeklewold - Why accept this answer if it didn't solve your problem?

Comment: am new to this web site